# writing OracleDataReader to excel C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oracle

I need help. How should I write each row from a table into an Excel file?

Question #1: how do I get the values of each cell or each row from `OracleDataReader`?

Question #2: number of columns in tables might vary. Should I read each cell and write it to Excel or by row?

Code:

```
try            
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection();
    connection.Open();

    if(connection.ToString().Equals("Open"))
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connection;

        cmd.Parameters.Add (dict_name);

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from :dict_name";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        OracleDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
        }
    }

    connection.Close();
}
catch (OracleException e)
{
    if (e.ErrorCode != 2000)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oracle Error -> {0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd mm yyyy HH:mm:ss"), e.StackTrace);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Erorr -> {0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd mm yyyy HH:mm:ss"), e.StackTrace);
}
```

Comment: Is :dict_name supposed to be the name of the table? This cannot work as parameters cannot be used to represent table or fields' names

Comment: @steve The parameter will come from outside with http response.

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the edit xD

Comment: Why not just use MS Query?  It's built into Excel

Comment: @Hambone I did it with NPOI.

Comment: Best exception handling ever!

Comment: @UweKeim was that sarcasm? xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. Here is the code that is working for me now. I tried it with different tables in Database.

Question: Anyone has idea how to read dynamically from excel and load data into database? I mean like, to construct INSERT command dynamically

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string dictToExcel(string dict_name)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConnection"].ConnectionString;
        OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from " + dict_name;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            OracleDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            IWorkbook workbook;
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

            ISheet sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Sheet 1");

            int b = 0;
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                int n = 0;
                IRow row = sheet.CreateRow(b);
                while (n < dataReader.FieldCount)
                {
                    ICell cell = row.CreateCell(n);

                    String columnName = dataReader.GetValue(n).ToString();
                    cell.SetCellValue(columnName);

                    n++;
                }

                b++;
            }
```